# Discount and transaction fee as separate rows on checkout

Tags: checkout, payment-methods, shopping-cart-price-rules

We have a **Magento Community Edition 1.9.2.1** which has a discount rule set up via **Shopping Cart Price rules**. Next to that, depending on the **payment method**, **transaction** and **processing fees** are also applied.

Currently this is shown as 1 line on the checkout:

[image: Combined discount and fees on checkout]

Is there any way to show these as separate rows on the checkout and in the order confirmation e-mails? Our sales support team needs to know the separate amounts for the **discount and transaction / processing fee**.

Thanks in advance,

Stijn

Answer (score 0):

Try Like Below code:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId('100000009');
$discountAmount = array();
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $discountAmount[$item->getId()] = $item->getBaseDiscountAmount(); //or getDiscountAmount()
}
```

Comment: This will not work as there is no order yet.